# Functions not loading from mysql dump

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

While taking a dump from my A server I have used `--routines` to get all the functions.
"mysqldump -u '' -p'' --routines --all-databases > db_backup.sql"
I am facing problem with loading the functions. The data has been loaded properly from the dump, but the functions are not.

I loaded the same dump in my local to check if functions are present, and it was present. Also all the schema were loaded right:

```
os= UBUNTU 18.04, mysql -V=5.7.3 
"SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;"
Output-6 rows
```

But when I loaded the same to B server, there where no functions.However, all the schema were loaded right:

```
os= UBUNTU 18.04, mysql -V=5.7.3,server- ec2 instance
"SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;"
Output-Empty
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Would really appreciate guidance.

Comment: aws doesn't support all mysql functions, so tell us please your function code or check of aws supports all what you use

Comment: one of my function is basic age difference calculator

Comment: have you checked if every function is supported by aws?

Comment: @nbk when i create the same functions again on the server by running a script, function gets created.